# How to get RAS connection status on Windows CE 4.2 with Compact Framework 1

Tags: .net, networking, compact-framework

can anyone tell me how to check if a Windows CE 4.2 device is currently connected to the Internet, i.e. how to get the RAS connection status (we are using RAS autodial)? I can of course do something like a DNS query, but I certainly would like to do this without actually generating data traffic ... or is this the only way?
I am still using Compact Framework 1, and I need to display the connection status in a full-screen kiosk mode application.

Thanks,
Timo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [Compact Framework RAS library over on CodePlex](http://rascf.codeplex.com/) that might be of use. I honestly don't remember if I wrote it against 1.0 or 2.0, but I know I did it a long time ago, so it's likely 1.0 compliant (or fairly easy to make it compliant).